# sudo command is not working in Vscode terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

I am using vscode in Linux Mint.
"sudo, root, npm" commands are not working in Vscode bash terminal. I can only use cd, ls and install commands.

```
yearmfew@mySpace:~/jules/clr-6$ npm
bash: npm: command not found
```

Answer (score 3):

It was because of flatpak. I have vscode from there installed. It is officially distributed in snap. I have downloaded from there and it is okay now.

Answer (score -1):

This is explained in the documentation for VS Code :  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_configuration
(which has various options), but to avoid this being a link-only answer:

Set the "terminal.integrated.shell.windows" VS Code configuration variable to "C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe" and you should be good to go.

For convenience, there's also a Select Default Shell command in the command palette which sets this for you.

Comment: But I am using linux mint. Will it still work?

Comment: Try to look here:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux